# Comparing Stock Prices

Tags: lua, compare, stock

I have a table full of different villages and their commodities, and the stock, buying, and selling price they have.

The table looks like this:

```
stocks = {
  village = {
    fish = {
      12,
      76,
      0
    },
    silver = {
      0,
      220,
      0
    },
    stone = {
      0,
      200,
      0
    },
    silk = {
      4,
      1100,
      0
    },
    salt = {
      0,
      10,
      0
    },
    wood = {
      23,
      0,
      49
    }
  },
}
```

It has three numbers in the commodity table, the first being the amount they have in stock (useful since if I'm comparing prices, i'd only want it to count if there were some in stock to buy!), second is the price they are buying for (higher the better), and the third the price they're selling it for (lower the better, and this is where stock comes in handy, being more than 0). I've tortured myself trying to come up with ways to make a nice function (like so, `prices("fish")`) that, when given a commodity to look for, will find the best places to buy and sell to make a profit.

The coding language I'm using to do this is Lua but I'm sure this could be done in many languages with the know-how ^_^

If someone could point me in the right direction here then I'd be forever greatful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a direction...

```
local function prices(commodity)
  for placeName, placeData in pairs(stocks) do
    local data = placeData[commodity]
    if (data) then
      print(placeName .. " has " .. data[1].. " " .. commodity)
      -- ...
    end
  end
  -- ...
end
```

I'm not clear on what results you're after but the above is one way to dig into the data structure.

Comment: Thank you for answering :) Funnily enough that is the exact function I came up with on my own but couldn't figure out how to sort two tables with all the highest buying price (data[2]), and others with the lowest selling price (data[3]). And then it would, once finished going  through all the tables, sort themselves properly and print out the best comparisons for profit in a descending order... I'll try to keep working on it myself. Any further ideas or tips would be appreciated though! :)

Comment: I figured out how to do it now. Thank you for your help! ^_^